# React Native & xcode - Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: xcode, react-native, ipad, deployment, codesign

I am just trying to deploy my sample app named "yoing" on my ipad.

This is just a simple create-react-native app and I haven't made any personal code inside yet. I was just following basic "getting started" instructions in official create-react-native app website.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device

I am using my macbook pro (13 early - if it helps.) as my dev machine and I already succeed in deploying this sample create-react-native code on my android device (galaxy j7).

PROBLEM IS, I CANNOT DEPLOY THIS SAME CODE VIA XCODE.
AS I PRESS THAT BUILD BUTTON ON XCODE TOOLBAR, IT ALWAYS ENDS WITH SAME ERROR : COMMAND CODESIGN ENDED WITH A NONZERO EXIT CODE

The whole error message looks just like below :

```
CodeSign /Users/heech/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/yoing-dsyowmyyswzmxdcdnysafvotxaik/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/yoing.app (in target: yoing)
    cd /Users/heech/Documents/yoing/ios
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate

Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: heech912@gmail.com (MD982C66KC)"
Provisioning Profile: "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: org.reactjs.native.example.yoing"
                      (dd34247a-2ddf-4825-b17f-e26321765eb1)

    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 7083B6622130B970E149032468DC4633F49EDDE8 --entitlements /Users/heech/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/yoing-dsyowmyyswzmxdcdnysafvotxaik/Build/Intermediates.noindex/yoing.build/Debug-iphoneos/yoing.build/yoing.app.xcent --timestamp=none /Users/heech/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/yoing-dsyowmyyswzmxdcdnysafvotxaik/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/yoing.app

/Users/heech/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/yoing-dsyowmyyswzmxdcdnysafvotxaik/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/yoing.app: errSecInternalComponent
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I expect no errors and successful deployment of my sample app "Yoing" right inside my ipad. heech is my account profile name.

I've already read all stack overflow threads regarding this issue, and tried every possible methods, while I always come up with same error.

Plz save my day.. I've spent half of my saturday doing this stuff.
I'm quite embarrased because I was able to deploy crna app about 2 years ago on the same ipad.

Someone familiar with this problem, plz relieve me from my pain...

additional info:
ipad : ipad 5
xcode : v 10.2

I'll be waiting like 24/7, so plz don't hesitate for any comments or replies. Thankyou

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I made it somehow.
Still, I don't know the exact reason why..
But I think there are some methods which I tried
which turns out to be quite successful.

1. go to keychain access, delete your previous certificate, and renew one.
2. go to keychain access, lock "login", build, and when password prompt shows up for your keychain authentication, input your device password and press "allow always" NOT 'allow'

hope some folks with similar problem get through this.

Comment: You raise me up!!